# Upload file with Batch program

Tags: batch-file, file-upload

Good afternoon all,

I am having an bit of trouble with the following Batch file.

```
@echo off
set /p Pass=Enter your password: 
ncftp <<EOF
open -u thomas -p %Pass% MyHost.com
cd "Program"
lcd "../Program"
put -R *
bye
EOF
```

It returns after the password the following error
<< not expected at this time

I have this script from somewhere on the internet. And if he does it it works like an charm.
What am i doing wrong or what must i do i have searched the internet with << but i didnt get any search results on that matter.

With kind regards,

Thomas de Vries

Comment: seems to be discussed to conclusion here http://forums.techguy.org/web-design-development/915228-ncftp-running-script.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The only thing is with ncftpput you are always uploading all the files no matter what. With ncftp you can upload only the newest modified files. The bad thing with ncftp is that its only reading the connection values from connect.cfg. The rest you need to add manualy to the prompt.

So i am looking for an way to upload latest modified files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in your script.

```
ncftp <<EOF
```

`<<EOF` is a syntax error  and `<EOF` would be redirecting a file called `EOF` in the same folder, into the `ncftp` executable.

It would seem that your source material is not quite debugged.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p Pass=Enter your password: 
(
echo open -u thomas -p %Pass% MyHost.com
echo cd "Program"
echo lcd "../Program"
echo put -R *
echo bye
) | ncftp
```

Comment: You tripped the low quality posts filter... You may want to flesh out your answer a bit in order to avoid deletion.

Comment: @apaul34208: I am afraid I don't understand what is the concern with my original answer, but I modified it in the same way as other answer here that did not received this warning. Perhaps if you extend on what "low quality posts filter" is I will avoid this problem in future posts...

Comment: Question/answers that trip the low quality filter end up in the [low quality posts review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) Usually it happens when a post is very short or code only. Chances are good that the other answers to this question went through the review as well, but no one bothered to comment on them. You may want to consider adding a little explanation as to why the code you posted answers the question.

Comment: @apaul34208: In my almost 3 years in this site I never had heard about this matter. A large number of my 926 answers (=17424 points) are comprised of just code so I am pretty sure that many of them had appeared in this listing before, but you are the first one that suggested me to modify an answer "in order to avoid deletion". I realized that answers in that listing may be just marked as "Looks Good", so I assume you did not reviewed my answer. This matter present a dilemma to me: should I modify my customary posting style in order to avoid your comments on low quality posts?

Comment: Perhaps my wording could have been a little better, avoiding deletion is only one good reason to try and offer a little more explanation in answers. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/217863

Comment: @apaul34208: It seems that there is too much to say about this matter; however, I have not any interest at all in a discussion on it. I not even had heard about this topic before your first comment here. I am just interested in a very single concrete point: how to avoid that you will post comments about low quality problems in my following answers? I reviewed your last 40 comments and found that in 16 of them you wrote some type of criticism, like "This does not provide an answer to the question...", "it would be better if you could add some explanation...", "possible duplicate", etc... So?

Comment: Most of those are comments that are automatically added by the system when performing reviews in the review queues...  Rather than voting to delete your post I opted to leave a comment, because I guessed that a user that had reached 17k would likely understand that I was choosing to encourage more complete answers rather than just deleting potentially valuable content.

Comment: It won't happen again.